# Арифметическое вычитание в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Получаю `NULL` при исполнении такого запроса:

```
select 300*count(*)-(NULL) as `col` from `table`
```

Вместо `(NULL)` у меня подзапрос, который в отдельности выдает `NULL`, когда убираю этот подзапрос то получаю число.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: так всегда бывает любые операции с `null` возвращают `null` я обычно добавляю `nvl((NULL))`

Comment: англ википедия вроде не плохо это описывает [см](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что это NULL

Сделайте `ifnull((subquery), 0)` или укажите другое значение вместо нуля, которое вам нужно здесь для корректного рассчёта.